# Opening activity by clicking on button located on a PopUpWindow (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do what the title says, but for some reason the application crashes when I click on the button.

The error it shows is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method show(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_1'

I have a MainActivity that contains a method to open a popupwindow from a button, (which seems to work fine but I'm writting it just in case) and is:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
private PopupWindow popUpWindow;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

}

public void newWindowPopup(View view){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int wide = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_popwindow, null);
    popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(container, (int)(wide*.7), (int)(height*.25), true);
    popUpWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
    popUpWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popUpWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Layout for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:background="#A85757"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFrases"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="newWindowPopup"
                    android:text="Button 1"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code for opening the activity from another button from the popwindow class I created, which seems to be where the trouble is:

public class popwindow extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popwindow);

    Button p_button=findViewById(R.id.btn_1);

    p_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent showActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(showActivity);
        }
    });
}


public void show(View view) {
    Intent showActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(showActivity);
}
```

}

Layout for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="EEEEE"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, the activity I'm trying to open from this popwindow (Main2Activity) doesn't have code yet, It's just an empty activity with a TextView.

The methods View are associated to the buttons with the onClick property so that's not the issue. Thank you very much if you can help.

Comment: from where show is being called?

Comment: The onClick property of the button. Maybe I deleted it on this code because I was trying the other method, but it's the way I was doing it previously.

Comment: is this crashing still after you have removed the code of onclick?

Comment: It's not crashing but it simply doesn't do anything when I try it with the listener instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a button on **popwindow** layout.

```
 <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Start Second Activity"/>
```

Then add following function to show popup and move to second activity

```
    public void newWindowPopup(View view){
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int wide = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popwindow, null);
        popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(container, (int)(wide*.7), (int)(height*.25), true);
        popUpWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
        popUpWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popUpWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });

        Button p_button=container.findViewById(R.id.button);  

        p_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) { 

            Intent showActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(showActivity); 
            }  
        });  
    }
```

Comment: I have the buttons and everything I need in the XML files (I didn't write that code because it's always the same), so that's not the issue. The "setOnClickListener" is just another way of doing the same, I have already the method view associated with the onClick property. Thanks anyways, but that's not it. EDIT: Oh, but I don't want the same button to open the popup and go to the next activity. I want a button to open the popup, and then on that popup there is another button that directs to the other activity.

Comment: So you want a single popup class .So u can access it from difrent and show the same popup and click it on button open the other activty according to the acticty which open the popup.
Is that right?

Comment: Let's see: I have a an activity in which, by clicking on a button, a popup which contains other buttons opens. Like this: https://postimg.cc/7G8qdXxF 

Then, by cliking on one of those buttons on the popup window (button 4 for example), it opens another activity.

Comment: Yes i think the problem is in your layout it cannot access the function "Show(view)". Set the on click listner on the java side as i show you code in answer hope it works.
And if not please show me your both xml layouts.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work with the listener, but anyways I need to do it by using the onClick property because I plan on using a lot of buttons and I can't repeat all that code. I edited the first post with both layouts, let me know if you need anything else (though the only thing that's left are the animations, you can delete those if you want, it's the same). Thanks again by the way.

Comment: Finaly i solve your problem. your layout is seems good just copy and paste my function "newWindowPopup" in your code.
the issue is you access the pop layout element without in activitty without accessing it. Now u have to do these following steps
1:Jsut copy my <Button> code and replace it with your popup window layout button code.
2:Just copy my "newWindowPopup" function and replace with your same function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. And I realized that there is a way for me to repeat less code even with this method, so everything is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and I didn't know I could do that. Done.